# Unable to mount the volume to the pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have k8tes cluster in which I am facing issues while mounting the existing volume to the pod in the new deployment. I have the existing deployments where I am mounting the same existing PV and PVCs. But facing issues only new deployment.

What could be the reason? How can I mount(NFS) volume to the new deployments because both PV and PVC statuses are bound and claimed respectively?

Answer (score 1):

you can not ideally If your mount mode is set to **ReadWriteOnce**.

If you are planning to use the NFS and want to attach multiple PODs to a single mount you have to use the **ReadWriteMany**.

Example :

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-data
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  storageClassName: nfs
```

> A PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC) is a request for storage by a user. It
> is similar to a Pod. Pods consume node resources and PVCs consume PV
> resources. Pods can request specific levels of resources (CPU and
> Memory). Claims can request specific size and access modes (e.g., they
> can be mounted ReadWriteOnce, ReadOnlyMany or ReadWriteMany, see
> AccessModes).

Acces mode : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes

GKE example : https://medium.com/platformer-blog/nfs-persistent-volumes-with-kubernetes-a-case-study-ce1ed6e2c266

Comment: Access mode is already set to ReadWriteMany in pvc config file.

Comment: share your config files for ref

Comment: Do I need to fix anything on mount server in terms of network connectivity because mount issue happened suddenly.

Comment: check the logs or events in deployment without that hard to say anything on that

Comment: ERROR message in event section: "timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod"

Comment: in every new deployment when I gave kctl describe <podname>

Comment: Also I have two namespaces with one namespace the deployments are OK, issue is only limited to another namespace.

Comment: Also the mount servers are different for both the namespaces.